# Deserializing JSON array of integers to List<Integer>

Tags: quarkus

I've got the following code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/sets")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PartitionSet {
    
    @Path("/form")
    @POST
    public Response create(List<List<BigDecimal>> partitions){
        Map<String, Integer> obj = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        obj.put("numPartitions", partitions.size());
        buildGraph(partitions);
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(obj).build();
    }
```

```
This actually works correctly, but I'd like to be able to have that argument to the "create" method be List<List<Integer>> instead of the BigDecimal that the jsonb deserializer seems to be using. Is there a way to do that?

My pom has the following dependency. Should I be using a different one to make this work?
```

`<dependency> <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId> <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jsonb</artifactId> </dependency>`
`

If I simply change the argument to `List<List<Integer>>`, there is no failure in the deserialization. However, when it comes to using the result of the deserialization (when I do `partitions.get(<some number>).get(<some number>)`), I get:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.math.BigDecimal and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

I'm not sure why the error message talks about which module those classes are in. Should I care?

[Edited to add]
Example of JSON provided as input:
[
[
16,    15,    2,    1
],
[
16,    14,    3,    1
]
]

[image: showing screenshot of exception with code that triggers it]

Comment: Can you add an example of your json?

Comment: @HerrDerb - added example . Based on the example provided, I'd get the ClassCaseException mentioned when I do `partitions.get(0).get(0)` if the argument to create had type of `List<List<Integer>>`.

Comment: This seems a bit odd... Does this happen during a test in which you might still use BigDecimal? On which line does the exception occure.?I hardly believe that it happens when you do `int value = partitions.get(0).get(0);`

Comment: @HerrDerb - I've added the photographic evidence :-)

Comment: When posting a stacktrace, its recommended to post all of it.  When you change `List<List<Integer>>` to `List<List<String>>` what values do you receive? I still have doubs.

Comment: I fixed this using the JsonbAdapter:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by defining a JsonbAdapter:

```
public class IntegerSerializer implements JsonbAdapter<Integer, BigDecimal>{

    @Override
    public BigDecimal adaptToJson(Integer obj) throws Exception {
        return new BigDecimal(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer adaptFromJson(BigDecimal obj) throws Exception {
        return obj.intValue();
    }
    
}
```

....which requires a JsonbConfigCustomizer:

```
@Singleton
public class IntegerSerConfig implements JsonbConfigCustomizer{

    @Override
    public void customize(JsonbConfig jsonbConfig) {
        System.out.println("Configuring....");
        jsonbConfig.withAdapters(new IntegerSerializer());
    }
    
}
```

For some reason, this would not work with the jsonb reactive extensions, so in my pom, I switched to the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```